# Legend label failed to send to print service using ArcGIS javascript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, printing

I am try to print my map with legend to PDF format; however, the legend label in the PDF is saying **Override 1** instead of the label I specified in class breaks.

There are other maps I can print successfully with the correct labels used and the only difference I can find between them is that the ClassBreaksRenderer constructor is called differently. While the maps that can successfully print with the legend label is passing string to the `attributeField` parameter like

```
var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(null, 'break_column_name');
```

the one failed to print the legend label is passing a function to the parameter like

```
var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(null, calculate_break);
```

I have searched the web and as someone suggested, looking at the JSON that sent to the print service, I found that that no information about the breaks (i.e. classBreakInfos) are sent to the service.

Does anyone know why it is the case and how can I fix it?

I am using the 3.10 API.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this GeoNet thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/101287) it appears that this is a limitation of the print task API. The ESRI staff member there stated:

> Unfortunately, i don't know how of a good way to work around this problem (other than ensuring that you have fields present in the data for values you need to render by.)